# How to format string as we need

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I have three type of string and i want to format that string to get street number, street name, city name.

```
The first type is : 34 Ellis Street, San Francisco
Here i want to make it like 
street number : 34
street name : Ellis Street
city name : San Francisco


The second type is : 4FL, 800 Market Street, San Francisco
Here i want to delete 4FL, 
And i want to make it like 
street number : 800
street name : Market Street
city name : San Francisco

The third type is : Ellis & Market, San Francisco
Here i want to make it like 
street number : 
street name : Ellis & Market
city name : San Francisco
```

How can i do this or any link that show string formatting like this than please suggest.And yes the string i write here is just a format of string i get,string will be changed every time.

Comment: If it is unique format we can sort out some logic and implement that, but here for each time it will give some improper text, We need to statically do this type of thing. We can fix if it is fixed format.

Comment: sorry @Madhu this string is return by google api and i have to display this string in three different textview as text in string.

Comment: You can use: [yourstring substringFromIndex:0];
             [yourstring substringToIndex:1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address string is passed to this method and then it is converted into an array having 3 string objects containing streetNumber, streetName and cityName. Then the array is returned to the caller.

```
-(NSArray *)brakeAddress:(NSString *)address{

     NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[address componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

     if (arr.count>2) {
     [arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     }

     NSInteger streetNameInd=[arr count]-2, cityNameInd=[arr count]-1;

     NSMutableArray *streetNameArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:arr[0], nil];

     if ([arr[streetNameInd] intValue]) {

     streetNameArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:([arr[streetNameInd] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "])];

     [streetNameArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     if ([streetNameArray[0] intValue] ==[arr[streetNameInd] intValue]) {
     [streetNameArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     }
     }

     NSString *streetName=[streetNameArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

     NSString *streetNumber=@"";
     if ([arr[streetNameInd] intValue]!=0) {
     streetNumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [arr[streetNameInd] intValue]];
     }

    NSString *city=arr[cityNameInd];
    // NSLog(@"\nstreet number :%@\nstreet name  :%@\ncity name :%@",streetNumber, streetName,city);

    NSArray *addressParts=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:streetNumber, streetName, city, nil];

    return addressParts;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    NSString *str1=@"34 Ellis Street, San Francisco";
    NSString *str2=@"4FL, 800 Market Street, San Francisco";
    NSString *str3=@"Ellis & Market, San Francisco";

    NSArray *firstAddress=[self brakeAddress:str1];
    NSArray *secondAddress=[self brakeAddress:str2];
    NSArray *thirdAddress=[self brakeAddress:str3];

    NSLog(@"\n1st : street number :%@\nstreet name  :%@\ncity name :%@",firstAddress[0],firstAddress[1],firstAddress[2]);
    NSLog(@"\n2nd : street number :%@\nstreet name  :%@\ncity name :%@",secondAddress[0],secondAddress[1],secondAddress[2]);
    NSLog(@"\n3rd : street number :%@\nstreet name  :%@\ncity name :%@",thirdAddress[0],thirdAddress[1],thirdAddress[2]);


}
```

Comment: it give error like "Subscript requires size of interface 'NSMutableArray', which is not constant in non-fragile ABI"

Comment: I am using the above code in mac os x application, ARC enabled and NO Warning No error, thats why i posted...

Comment: replace everywhere `arr[index]` to `[arr objectAtIndex:index]` and try again

Comment: by replacing everywhere arr[index] to [arr objectAtIndex:index].as u said.

Comment: i not able to copy the value of streetNumber, streetName, arr[cityNameInd] in my other method?

Comment: these are local to this method, you cant use them there. If you want to use, create a string my appending all three. pass that string to that method. Or, you can use a class property, to use it throughout your class.

Comment: if i create array and then pass this array to second method than does that work

Comment: Yes you can do, kindly check my updated as per your requirement.

Comment: and i use this array in my class,everywhere?

Comment: NOOOO. if you want a global array, go for a property or ivar.

Comment: actually i have difine array in .h file and add value of street city and street number vue in it and than use that array in another method.

Comment: For property you need to assign once while you want to convert (see my edited code again, as i have passed a long string and broken it into array,) and again i nslog-ed it by appending it to an string.

Answer (score 1):

1) Separate with:

```
NSArray *arrayOfComponents = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

2) The last component will always be your city name

3) Then check the (Last - 1) component with

```
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

2) Take the FIRST element of the array and use this

```
NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
{
    // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
}
```

3) If it has only digits then, the FIRST element is your street number, and just make a new string by appending the remaining elements to get the street name. Else the past (last -1) from the previous array is the street name.

**This is the basic idea, the logic can obviously be improved.**

Edit: since you mentioned that this string is provided by google api it means you are probably getting a JSON response. You should use the complete JSON response to get your textfields filled. There is a JSON to NSDictionary Class you can use:see [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be first you can implement code to break the address string into different variables such as `_streetNum,_streetName,_cityName` then you can use following code line for formatting the string

```
NSString* formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"street number : %@\nstreet name :%@\ncity name :%@",_streetNum,_streetName,_cityName];
```

Comment: But that's the problem how can i break the string which gives me three types of string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

It will give you an array wsth all strings separated by " ";

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way and parse the response whatever you need related to that address

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=34%20Ellis%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,+CA&sensor=true
```

HOpe it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regular Expressions. Have a look at this: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that might help you.

```
NSString *addressString;
NSArray *tempArray = [addressString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
if([tempArray count]==3){
    city = [tempArray objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *tempString = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];

    NSArray *temp1Array = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    if ([temp1Array count]>1) {
        st_num = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
        st_name = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",st_num] withString:@""];
    }
}
```

You can extend its logic for your requirement.